# Type "GUID" is not defined

Tags: vb.net

I'm encountering this error on this line of code:

```
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@address2", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = IIf(Address2.Trim.Length &gt; 0,Address2, DBNull.Value)
```

> Type "GUID" is not defined.
>
> Name IIf and DBNull are not declared

How can this be fixed?

```
Private Shared Function Update(ByVal ID As <b>Guid</b>, ByVal Name As String, ByVal Address1 As String, ByVal Address2 As String, ByVal City As String, ByVal State As String, ByVal Zip As String) As Integer
    Dim cn As New SqlConnection(sqlConn)
    cn.Open()
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder
    With sb
        .Append("Update Vendor ")
        .Append("set ")
        .Append("vendor_name = @name, ")


  Public Class Vendor
  Inherits BaseClass
#Region " Local Variables"
   Protected _id As Guid
```

Comment: Could explain a little bit the context and format the piece of code you're giving because it's unreadable right now.

Comment: Can you try and edit you code into something that will compile? As it stands it is difficult to help because we don't know where to start

Comment: The code you posted will not compile or is incomplete.  There is no End Function, nor is there an End Class.  Please show *complete* code that illustrates the problem you are having.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to use the fully qualified name  `System.Guid`.
e.g.

```
ByVal ID As System.Guid
```

Or try importing the `System` namespace, will also catch `DBNull`, and probably IIf too.